# Desk calendar icon

Tags: discussion, icons, calendar

Somewhere on some Stack Exchange site, there's an icon that shows a day of the month styled like a desk calendar. I cannot for the life of me remember where I saw this and would like to track it down in order to see how it was done (from a CSS/HTML point of view).

Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

### Update

I'm not referring to the days visited calendar. The thing I'm looking for is like a desktop calendar that only shows a single day of the year, similar to this:

[image: page-a-day-style calendar displaying Nov 10]

Comment: Are you talking about the "days visited" link on your profile?

Comment: @ChrisF no, I've updated my question with some further details

Comment: Perhaps it's in chat - http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=schedule?

Comment: @ChrisF yes, that's it, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edit: Turns out you meant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130172/desk-calendar-widget#comment357127_130172) [the chat one.](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=schedule). Keeping this answer there for people from the future.

---

Yep. You mean this fellow?

[image]

Go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648/don) (seeing your rep, I guess the link is unnecessary :P) and click the "visited: x days, y consecutive" text-link-invisible-thingy. You'll see a calendar, with green stuff on all the days you visited.